How to store shedlock details to elastic search using spring
I want to use shedlock for my spring application and want to keep track of lock information for my schedulers in elastic search index, not finding any useful resources.
I tried with Cassandra db and it's working perfect and it's not working when it comes to elastic search
I tried to use RestHighLevelClient it's throwing that it's deprecated but unable to find latest library for this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
